# Disable Sails.js static asset serving

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

How can I completely turn off static assets?  I was thinking I might be able to do:

```
module.exports = {

// Init custom express middleware
express: {

    customMiddleware: function (app) {
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/some_empty_folder'));
```

But that doesn't seem good to me.  Is there a way to turn off static asset serving in the configuration?

Comment: Hello! Have you been able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SlavaFominII Nope, unless the answer below by jorgecasar works for you.  Based on what he said, maybe it is possible to modify the grunt tasks after the app is created, maybe even switching on and off assets programmatically.  It also might be possible to do some kind of symlinking of the asset folder in a script, although that isn't great because it wouldn't be platform independent and would need some kind of reversal when the app closes I think.

Comment: Thank you @light24bulbs! Please see the answer by major Sails.js contributor @sgress454. I think it should solve the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off serving of static assets by removing the [`www` middleware](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware?q=conventional-defaults) from the [middleware.order](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.http.html?q=properties) in [/config/http.js](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.http.html):

```
module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {

   order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      // 'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ]

  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a sails app without front-end with the flag --no-frontend

```
sails new [appName] --no-frontend
```

This will avoid to create asset folder and grunt tasks.

Comment: Ah that's cool.  But in my case, I am looking for a way to disable it programmatically at run time.  I want to have two deploys of the same server, one which serves the API and one which serves the assets based on an environment variable.  I realized it's ok if the API server also serves static assets in my case, I just won't use that part of it.  It's the asset server which truly needs to have the API turned off, and I was able to do that by disabling the automatic routing and the custom routes based on a variable.  Thanks for the input!  I'm sure that will help somebody